# Javascript array to json (Newtonsoft.Json)

Tags: xml, json, vb.net, parsing, xpath

I need to scrape a website which returns an javascript array

like this:

```
[{
    trip:1,
    date: 15-06-2014,
    leg: 2,
    type: "tree"
},
{
    trip:4,
    date: 01-12-2014,
    leg: 14,
    type: "house"
}]
```

Now I need to get acces to this data the XPath way.
So I tought, I need to convert this array to a JSON object or an XML object with Newtonsoft.Json.
But I have no idea how to do that.

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: How are you getting the data?

Comment: Since your object only contains data.  You can simply JSON.stringify(obj) to get the json.  Why do you want to XPath?

Comment: Well, actually this is in the sourcecode of the scraped page.

Like: "<head><script>items=[{things in openingspost}]</script></head>"